# JavaScript click sibling in nested html

Tags: javascript, dom-events

First I need to do this all in JavaScript.

What I am trying to achieve is find the `<a>` tag by href value and then click the sibling `<a>` element with the class "open-menu".

This is what I have attempted below, and it works if I call the final command of `clickThis.click();` from the browser console. However, it does not register on its own.

Sample menu code:

```
<li class="with-sub-menu click">
  <p class="close-menu"></p>
  <p class="open-menu"></p>
  <a href="benches" class="clearfix"
     target="_blank"><span><strong>Benches</strong></span></a>
  <div class="sub-menu" style="width: 350%; display: none;">
    <div class="content">
      <p class="arrow"></p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12  mobile-enabled">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 hover-menu">
              <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/benches/Indoor-Benches"
                       onclick="window.location = 'http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/benches/Indoor-Benches';"
                       class="main-menu ">Indoor Benches</a></li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/benches/Outdoor-Benches" 
                       onclick="window.location = 'http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/benches/Outdoor-Benches';"
                       class="main-menu ">Outdoor Benches</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Sample code:

```
<?php
   $r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
   $urlParse = explode('/', $r);
   $categoryName = $urlParse[1];
   echo($categoryName);
?>    
<script type="text/javascript">
   var el = document.querySelector("a[href='<?php echo($categoryName); ?>']");
   var parent = els.parentNode;
   var clickThis = parent.getElementsByClassName('open-menu');
   clickThis.click();
</javascript>
```

It does not produce any errors. However, it does not click. That is, until I run `clickThis.click();` from the browser console.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

So I have made the edits suggested as seen below, the result in the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: clickThis.click is not a function"

The updated code is

```
<?php  
    $r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $urlParse = explode('/', $r);
    $categoryName = $urlParse[1];
    echo($categoryName);
?>    
<script type="text/javascript">

    var el = document.querySelector("a[href='<?php echo($categoryName); ?>']");
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    var clickThis = parent.getElementsByClassName('open-menu');
    clickThis.click();

</script>
```

However, if I do the following it does not run the 'click' event on page load. But if I run `clickThis.click();` in the browser console, it expands the benches as I want. For some reason it is not kicking off after the page load.

```
<?php
    $r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $urlParse = explode('/', $r);
    //$categoryName = str_replace('-', ' ', $urlParse[1]);
    $categoryName = $urlParse[1];
    echo($categoryName);
?>    
<script type="text/javascript">        
    var el = document.querySelector("a[href='<?php echo($categoryName); ?>']");
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    var clickThis = parent.childNodes.item(1);
    clickThis.click();  
</script>
```

Comment: Its right before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are some obvious errors in this JavaScript:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
   var el = document.querySelector("a[href='<?php echo($categoryName); ?>']");
   var parent = els.parentNode;
   var clickThis = parent.getElementsByClassName('open-menu');
   clickThis.click();
</javascript>
```

**Error 1**: Wrong variable name 'els'

```js
var el = document.querySelector("a[href='...']");
var parent = els.parentNode; // 'els' is undefined
```

Fixing the 'els' error, `parent = el.parentNode` is the parent node of the `<a>` element. Here's one of those `<li>` elements with its descendants:

```html
<li><a
    href="http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/benches/Outdoor-Benches"
    onclick="window.location = 'http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/benches/Outdoor-Benches';"
    class="main-menu ">Outdoor Benches</a>
</li>
```

So `parent` in this case would be the `<li>` element.

**Error 2**: `getElementsByClassName()` returns zero elements

```
var clickThis = parent.getElementsByClassName('open-menu');
```

This will get an HTMLCollection of all child elements of `<li>` that have the `open-menu` class.

There are no child elements of `<li>` with class `open-menu`, so the HTMLCollection is empty.

**Error 3**: Using HTMLElement `click()` method on an empty HTMLCollection

```
clickThis.click();
```

This is attempting to call the `click()` method on an empty HTMLCollection. Even if the HTMLCollection were not empty, this is still wrong. `click()` is a method of HTMLElement, not of an HTMLCollection.

**Error 4**: Wrong closing tag `</javascript>`

```
</javascript>
```

There is no such tag name. This should be `</script>`.

---

**Comments on Update**

**Error 1** and **Error 2** have now been fixed in the **Update** section of the question:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    var el = document.querySelector("a[href='<?php echo($categoryName); ?>']");
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    var clickThis = parent.getElementsByClassName('open-menu');
    clickThis.click();

</script>
```

But **Error 2** and **Error 3** still remain. The reported error message is:

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: clickThis.click is not a function"
```

This error is generated because `clickThis` is not an HTMLElement, as explained above.

---

**Comments on Answer**

The author of the original question has replied in a [separate posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61819508/3113485) that this code revision works:

```js
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
  if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
    var el = document.querySelector('a[href=\'<?php echo($categoryName); ?>\']');
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    var clickThis = parent.childNodes.item(1);
    clickThis.click();
  }
});
```

This revision indeed resolves all of the reported **Errors 1-4**, and it wisely delays its execution until page load is complete.

However, the revised code does not fulfill the requirement:

> find the `a` tag by href value and then click the sibling element

as it issues a click on the found `<a>` tag that matches `$categoryName`, not its sibling.

---

**Final Update — A Full Rewrite**

To bring this 'error-fix-error' cycle to a close, below is a simple rewrite that meets the (restated) requirement:

> click on anchor tag that doesn't match the category name provided in the URL

This rewrite also eliminates the server-side PHP, satisfying the requirement:

> *I need to do this all in JavaScript*

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let requestURI = location.href;
  let categoryName = requestURI.split('/').pop();
  let anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.main-menu'));
  let sibling = anchors.find(a => !a.href.includes(categoryName));
  sibling.click();
});
```

Comment: Actually part of this is incorrect. The selected element that is being selected is the following because I am actually searching off the category name which is in the href as below.
```
<a href="benches" class="clearfix"
     target="_blank"><span><strong>Benches</strong></span></a>
```
That means the parent is 
```
<li class="with-sub-menu click">
```
I have updated my post with my new code that I have and it results in an error which I have put in the update of my post.

Comment: @TheGugaru My answer is correct. You did not fix all the reported errors. I will update my answer to explain the errors that persist in your updated post. In addition, there is no such `<li class="with-sub-menu click">` in the HTML posted.  Yes, the `parent` is the `<li>` (as stated in my post). But it has no assigned classes.

Comment: Odd I don't get those errors and I get the end result I was after per my post. The sub menu expands when it is clicked. I have tested by outputting everything to the console and all elements are selected and interacted with as expected. IDK what you are testing off of but I get no errors and does exactly what I wanted it to do. It clicks the sibling element that has the class 'open-menu'. If you would like to see this in action you can see it in action here -> http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/ click a parent or child cat text and when the page reloads, clicks 'open-menu' expanding the parent.

Comment: The only error there is when the page is loaded without a category being in the URL and then I get a null reference to el. Which I will add a test for el being null when I return to my office.
Your solution does work too it just goes about selecting the href value a different way and doesn't use PHP either.

Comment: @TheGugaru This code of yours `var clickThis = parent.childNodes.item(1);` will always pick the anchor tag matching your `$categoryName`, not its sibling. See my answer for details.

Comment: Actually when I check it I always get the second one which is 'open-menu'. I will turn the output on tomorrow at some point so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the solution was actually more simple than I thought. It was because it wasn't activating after the page load, rather it was kicking off before the page had completed loading. So I used an event listener and kicked it off when the readyState was equal to "complete" and it works like a charm!

```
<?php
    $r = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    $urlParse = explode('/', $r);
    //$categoryName = str_replace('-', ' ', $urlParse[1]);
    $categoryName = $urlParse[1];
    echo($categoryName);
?>    
<script type="text/javascript">        
    document.addEventListener('readystatechange', event => {
        if (event.target.readyState === "complete") {
            var el = document.querySelector("a[href='<?php echo($categoryName); ?>']");
            var parent = el.parentNode;
            var clickThis = parent.childNodes.item(1);
            clickThis.click();  
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is still wrong, as it clicks on the `$categoryName` `<a>` element,, not its sibling `<a>` element. See the updates to my answer.